# Есть ли горячая клавиша для добавления включаемых пакетов в Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Нужно чтобы Eclipse сам определил, какие пакеты включить, и добавил их в список import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть. Это **Ctrl-Shift-O**.